# How to group ancestors in parent-child chains

Tags: sql, group-by, parent-child

I have two columns in a table such as:

```
ID1,ID2
1,2
3,4
4,5
7,8
8,10
9,10
9,11
11,12
..,..
```

So, I want to associate these IDs in same group like that:

```
ID Group_ID
1,1
2,1
3,2
4,2
5,2
7,3
8,3
9,3
10,3
11,3
12,3
..,..
```

PS: In these example, 3 equal to 4 and 4 equal to 5 so that 4 should be equal to 5. And also, 7,8,9,10,11,12 should be same group id. I am trying to do that if A=B and B=C then A should be equal to C (A=C).

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is a tradition here, that you show what you have tried, and explain, where exactly your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Not pretty but this works using regular SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT ID1 AS ID, Group_ID
 FROM
 (SELECT t1.ID1 AS ID1,
         t1.ID2 AS ID2,
         t2.ID1 AS ID3,
         t2.ID2 AS ID4,
         (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
          FROM ids t3
          LEFT JOIN ids t4
          ON t3.ID2 = t4.ID1
          OR (t3.ID1 = t4.ID1 AND t3.ID2 <> t4.ID2)
          OR (t3.ID2 = t4.ID2 AND t3.ID1 <> t4.ID1)
          WHERE (t3.ID1 < t1.ID1 
                 OR (t3.ID1 = t1.ID1 AND t3.ID2 < t1.ID2))
          AND t4.ID1 IS NULL) AS Group_ID
  FROM ids t1
  LEFT JOIN ids t2
  ON t1.ID2 = t2.ID1
  OR (t1.ID1 = t2.ID1 AND t1.ID2 <> t2.ID2)
  OR (t1.ID2 = t2.ID2 AND t1.ID1 <> t2.ID1)) sub1
 UNION DISTINCT
 SELECT ID2 AS ID, Group_ID
 FROM
 (SELECT t1.ID1 AS ID1,
         t1.ID2 AS ID2,
         t2.ID1 AS ID3,
         t2.ID2 AS ID4,
         (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
          FROM ids t3
          LEFT JOIN ids t4
          ON t3.ID2 = t4.ID1
          OR (t3.ID1 = t4.ID1 AND t3.ID2 <> t4.ID2)
          OR (t3.ID2 = t4.ID2 AND t3.ID1 <> t4.ID1)
          WHERE (t3.ID1 < t1.ID1 
                 OR (t3.ID1 = t1.ID1 AND t3.ID2 < t1.ID2))
          AND t4.ID1 IS NULL) AS Group_ID
  FROM ids t1
  LEFT JOIN ids t2
  ON t1.ID2 = t2.ID1
  OR (t1.ID1 = t2.ID1 AND t1.ID2 <> t2.ID2)
  OR (t1.ID2 = t2.ID2 AND t1.ID1 <> t2.ID1)) sub2
) sub3
ORDER BY ID
```

See [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/92fd2/23)

Comment: Hi,

First of all thanks for your help.

If the data is like that:

ID1, ID2

1 2

3 4

4 5

7 8

8 10

9 10

9 11

11 12

Query Result:

ID, Group_ID

1 1

2 1

3 2

4 2

5 2

7 3

8 3

9 5

10 3

10 5

11 5

12 5

9,10,11,12 IDs should be same group id.

Thanks

Comment: OK - please modify the question to also include those values + the expected result.

Comment: I think I find solution but I dont understand the solution for oracle db : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033115/how-to-label-transitive-groups-with-sql?s=d81951ed-6e85-41f0-a1ee-fe135020da67#new-answer

Comment: there is no any solution

Comment: OK have now edited my answer - please see if this works for you.