# How to convert code from Postgres to Oracle

Tags: oracle, postgresql

I have a source table (T1):

```
ID1 | ID2
----------
1   | 2
1   | 5
4   | 7
7   | 8
9   | 1
```

I want to convert the data to this (T2):

```
ID1 | ID2 | LABEL
------------------
1   | 2   | 1
1   | 5   | 1
4   | 7   | 2
7   | 8   | 2
9   | 1   | 1
```

I found a solution for this in PostgreSQL:

```
with 
recursive cte(id1, id2) as (
 select id1, id2, 1 as level
 from t
 union all
 select t.id1, cte.id2, cte.level + 1
 from t join
      cte
      on t.id2 = cte.id1
)
select id1, id2,
   dense_rank() over (order by grp) as label
from (select id1, id2,
         least(min(id2) over (partition by id1), min(id1) over (partition by id2)) as   grp,
         level
  from cte
 ) t
where level = 1;
```

I want to convert this code to Oracle. How I can convert this code from Postgres to Oracle?

Comment: No I only found that I should use "connect_by_root()" because of the recursive in oracle. Link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL

Comment: Please specify your Oracle version. That should work with Oracle 11.2 (as the recursive CTEs were introduced there). You might need to use something different than `LEVEL` because that is a reserved word.

Comment: Yes, it is Oracle 11g R2. Could you please help me? It is called "transitive relation" convertion.

Comment: This can't be done in single SQL statement. Please read through the comment to the [answer from which you grab original PostgreSQL query](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18033635/232279) to find examples where this concrete variant not worked. To reach you target grouping must continue while at least one pair of groups merged on previous step.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle 11.2 supports recursive CTEs. But it deviates from the standard in that the `recursive` keyword is not required (actually: must not be used). So if you remove the `recursive` keyword and get the definition of the CTE columns right the following should work. You also need to use something different than `LEVEL` as that is a reserved word either.

```
with cte (id1, id2, lvl) as (
 select id1, id2, 1 as lvl
 from t
 union all
 select t.id1, cte.id2, cte.lvl + 1
 from t 
   join cte on t.id2 = cte.id1
)
select id1, 
       id2,
       dense_rank() over (order by grp) as label
from (
  select id1, 
         id2,
         least(min(id2) over (partition by id1), min(id1) over (partition by id2)) as   grp,
         lvl
  from cte
 ) t
where lvl = 1;
```

Here is an SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/deeb2/3

However I doubt that the original query was correct as you do not have a "starting condition" for the recursive CTE. The first part of the union retrieves *all* rows of the table. There should be a condition to restrict that to the "roots" of the hierarchy unless I'm mis-understanding the purpose of the query.

A recursive CTE can also be replaced with a `CONNECT BY` query, in your case this would be:

```
select id1, id2, level as lvl
from t
connect by prior id1 = id2;
```

You can combine that with the orginal query:

```
with cte (id1, id2, lvl) as (
  select id1, id2, level as lvl
  from t
  connect by prior id1 = id2
)
select id1, 
       id2,
       dense_rank() over (order by grp) as label
from (
  select id1, 
         id2,
         least(min(id2) over (partition by id1), min(id1) over (partition by id2)) as  grp,
         lvl
 from cte
) t
where lvl = 1;
```

Although I think it should be the same, it seems that the hierarchy is traversed in a different order. Could be because the recursive CTE does a breadth first and the `connect by` a depth first recursion (or the other way round).

SQLFiddle example for the second version: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/deeb2/4

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. It the oracle version is not oracle 11g r2. How I can found another solution for it. Do you have any idea bout it?

Comment: `connect by` works with any Oracle version since 8.x. But you said it **is** 11.2?

Comment: Unfortunetly, it did not work above query. I am getting like this:

ID1 | ID2 | LABEL
------------------

1   | 2   | 1

1   | 5   | 1

4   | 7   | 2

7   | 8   | 3

9   | 1   | 1