# How to label a big set of “transitive groups” with a constraint?

Tags: sql, algorithm

EDIT after @NealB solution: the @NealB's solution is very very fast comparated with [any another one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18033115#answers), and **dispenses this new question about "add a constraint to improve performance"**. The @NealB's not need any improve, have *O(n)* time and is very simple.

---

The problem of "[label transitive groups with SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18033115/287948)" have [an elegant solution using recursion and CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18033635/287948)... But this solution consumes an exponential time (!). I need to work with 10000 itens: with 1000 itens need 1 second, with 2000 need 1 day...

*Constraint*: in my case is possible to break the problem into pieces of ~100 itens or less, but only to select one group of ~10 itens, and discard all the other ~90 labeled itens...

**There are a generic algotithm to add and use this kind of "pre-selection", to reduce the quadratic, *O(N^2)*, time?**  Perhaps, as showed by comments and @wildplasser, a *O(N log(N))* time; but I expect, with "pre-selection" to reduce to *O(N)* time.

---

(EDIT)

I try to use [alternative algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20608421/287948), but it need some improvement to use as solution here; or, to really increase performance (to *O(N)* time), need to use "pre-selection".

The "pre-selection" (constraint) is based on a "super-set grouping"... Stating by the original ["How to label 'transitive groups' with SQL?" question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18033115/287948) `t1` table,

```
  table T1
  (original T1 augmented by "super-set grouping label" ssg, and more one row)
  ID1 | ID2 | ssg
  1   | 2   | 1
  1   | 5   | 1
  4   | 7   | 1
  7   | 8   | 1 
  9   | 1   | 1
  10  | 11  | 2
```

So there are three groups,

- `g1`: {1,2,5,9} because "1 *t* 2", "1 *t* 5" and "9 *t* 1"
- `g2`: {4,7,8} because "4 *t* 7" and "7 *t* 8"
- `g3`: {10,11} because "10 *t* 11"

The super-group is only a auxiliary grouping,

- `ssg1`: {g1,g2}
- `ssg2`: {g3}

If we have *M* super-group-items and *N* total `T1` items, the average group length will be less tham  N/M.  We can suppose (for my typical problem) also that `ssg` maximum length is ~N/M.

So, **[the "label algorithm"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18033115/287948#tabs) need to run only M times with ~N/M items** if it use the `ssg` constraint.

Comment: I think there're better languages than SQL for this. And I don't know about SQL (for this particular task) but I think the time would not be exponential if using some other language. 10 000 items is a relatively small graph, I don't see how one can achieve exponential time for such a small task.

Comment: Yes, I can use [PL/pgSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/pgSQL) procedural language (!). If there are *no* "theoretical exponential grow " (?!), perhaps the problem is the recusion stack of the implementation...

Comment: No, I mean why don't you load these items, process them say in Java or C# or whatever, then update their group LABELs in the DB. And done. Your relation is only transitive right? Or is it an equivalence relation?

Comment: With respect to graph theory this is not a complex problem. Not exponential for sure. Not sure what this exponential notes are talking about (maybe something which is impl-dependent).

Comment: Only transitive, is a topological set, I am grouping by neighborhood. The *constraints* can be (always) geometrical or (not always) a super-set-label -- my itens are *urban plots* to be grouped by regional sectors or by "sets of *urban blocks*", see [some ex. of context of here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/80498/7505).

Comment: CTE recursion only appears to be "*elegant*" to client programmers who don't understand how bad it is in most cases.  It really should be regarded as a last resort solution.

Comment: Thank you @RBarryYoung, now I see the "bad face" of CTE recursion, by the performance problems... So, how you suggest to translate the recursion, to an (less elegant but) better performance procedure?

Comment: @PeterKrauss The first comment here is really the best: Although I am a huge fan of SQL, tracing long chains of links just isn't what it's good at.  If you need to diagram/trace 10,000 items, you'd probably be better off pulling it into your client all at once and then dealing with it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An SQL only soulution appears to be a bit of a problem here. With the help of some procedural
programming on top of SQL the solution appears to be failry simple and efficient. Here is a brief outline
of a solution as could be implemented using any procedural language invoking SQL.

Declare table `R` with primary key `ID` where `ID` corresponds the same domain as `ID1` and `ID2` of table `T1`.
Table `R` contains one other non-key column, a `Label` number

Populate table `R` with the range of values found in `T1`. Set `Label` to zero (no label).
Using your example data, the initial setup for `R` would look like:

```
Table R
ID Label
== =====
 1 0
 2 0
 4 0
 5 0
 7 0
 8 0
 9 0
```

Using a host language cursor plus an auxiliary counter, read each row from `T1`. Lookup `ID1` and `ID2` in `R`. You will find one of
four cases:

```
 Case 1: ID1.Label == 0 and ID2.Label == 0
```

In this case neither one of these `ID`s have been "seen" before: Add 1 to the counter and then update both
rows of `R` to the value of the counter: `update R set R.Label = :counter where R.ID in (:ID1, :ID2)`

```
 Case 2: ID1.Label == 0 and ID2.Label <> 0
```

In this case, `ID1` is new but `ID2` has already been assigned a label. `ID1` needs to be assigned to the
same label as `ID2`: `update R set R.Lablel = :ID2.Label where R.ID = :ID1`

```
 Case 3: ID1.Label <> 0 and ID2.Label == 0
```

In this case, `ID2` is new but `ID1` has already been assigned a label. `ID2` needs to be assigned to the
same label as `ID1`: `update R set R.Lablel = :ID1.Label where R.ID = :ID2`

```
 Case 4: ID1.Label <> 0 and ID2.Label <> 0
```

In this case, the row contains redundant information. Both rows of `R` should contain the same Label value. If not,
there is some sort of data integrity problem. Ahhhh... not quite see edit...

**EDIT** I just realized that there are situations where both `Label` values here could be non-zero and different. If both are non-zero and different then two `Label` groups need to be merged at this point. All you need to do is choose one `Label` and update the others to match with something like: `update R set R.Label to ID1.Label where R.Label = ID2.Label`. Now both groups have been merged with the same `Label` value.

Upon completion of the cursor, table `R` will contain Label values needed to update `T2`.

```
Table R
ID Label
== =====
 1 1
 2 1
 4 2
 5 1
 7 2
 8 2
 9 1
```

Process table `T2`
using something along the lines of: `set T2.Label to R.Label where T2.ID1 = R.ID`. The end result should be:

```
  table T2
  ID1 | ID2 | LABEL 
  1   | 2   | 1
  1   | 5   | 1
  4   | 7   | 2
  7   | 8   | 2
  9   | 1   | 1
```

This process is puerly iterative and should scale to fairly large tables without difficulty.

Comment: This is *Graph Theory* in action, thanks a LOT! Your algorithm is simple and fast, is the best! PS: can I add a complete code example at/as your answer? it is working and very fast!

Comment: @PeterKrauss Add whatever you want... I think there is a slight error in my analysis of case 4 though... If the labels are different it just means two labels are merging and you should update all of them to the same value. I will add an edit to explain in a couple of minutes....

Comment: OPS, your edit causes an "perhaps infinite" loop in the algorithm (in the "merge update")... It was fast but now is very slow... I am also analysing...

Comment: For Case 4: Update labels only if both are not zero and they are not equal to each other. If equal leave them as-is. If you do that, I don't think it would lead to poor performance or an infinite loop :-)

Comment: Sorry, I was using a sample-set of 40000  items with some failure (in my relationships generator), producing a *worst case*.  See [my worst-case explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033115#20608421).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check this and use some 
general-purpose language for solving it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure

Traverse the graph, maybe run DFS or BFS from each node, 
then use this disjoint set hint. I think this should work.

Comment: Hum... Thanks (!). Now I must to do my home-work and study: **1)** if your clue really  leads to the solution of [the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18033115/287948);  **2)** use the clues for develop an "the `log(n)` algorithm solution"; and **3)** implement `log(n)` solution with PL/pgSQL procedural language. So, if you can complete your answer with more one or two of these itens... (I'll thank you again).

Comment: The basic structure of disjoint-sets is the "union-find" algoritm, inpect all (N*N) pairs but use some coloring+pruning, reducing it to N log(N).

Answer (score 0):

The @NealB solution is the faster(!) See an [example of PostgreSQL implementation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20608421/287948).

Below an example of another "brute force algorithm", only for curiosity!

---

As @peter.petrov and  @RBarryYoung suggested, some performance problems can be avoided abandoning the CTE recursion... I [do some issues at the basic labeler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20608421/287948), and, abover I add the constraint for grouping by a super-set label. This new `transgroup1_loop()` function is working!

PS: this solution still have performance limitations, please post your answer with better, or with some adaptation of this one.

---

```
 -- DROP table transgroup1;
 CREATE TABLE transgroup1 (
   id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   items integer[], -- two or more items in the transitive relationship
   ssg_label varchar(12), -- the super-set gropuping label 
   dels integer[] DEFAULT array[]::integer[]
 );
 INSERT INTO transgroup1(items,ssg_label)  values
      (array[1, 2],'1'),
      (array[1, 5],'1'),
      (array[4, 7],'1'),
      (array[7, 8],'1'),
      (array[9, 1],'1'),
      (array[10, 11],'2');
 -- or  SELECT array[id1, id2],ssg_label FROM t1,  with 10000 items
```

them, with these two functions we can solve the problem,

```
  CREATE FUNCTION transgroup1_loop(p_ssg varchar, p_max_i integer DEFAULT 100) 
  RETURNS integer AS $funcBody$
    DECLARE
       cp_dels integer[];
       i integer;
    BEGIN
       i:=1;
       LOOP
           UPDATE transgroup1
           SET items = array_uunion(transgroup1.items,t2.items),
               dels =  transgroup1.dels || t2.id
           FROM transgroup1 AS t1, transgroup1 AS t2
          WHERE transgroup1.id=t1.id AND t1.ssg_label=$1 AND 
                t1.id>t2.id AND t1.items && t2.items;

           cp_dels := array(
               SELECT DISTINCT unnest(dels) FROM transgroup1
           ); -- ensures all itens to del

           RAISE NOTICE '-- bug, repeting dels, item-%; % dels!  %', i, array_length(cp_dels,1),  array_to_string(cp_dels,';','*');

           EXIT WHEN i>p_max_i OR array_length(cp_dels,1)=0;

           DELETE FROM transgroup1 
           WHERE ssg_label=$1 AND id IN (SELECT unnest(cp_dels));

           UPDATE transgroup1 SET dels=array[]::integer[];
           i:=i+1;
       END LOOP;
       UPDATE transgroup1         -- only to beautify
       SET items = ARRAY(SELECT unnest(items) ORDER BY 1 desc);
       RETURN i;
     END;
  $funcBody$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

to run and see results, you can use

```
 SELECT transgroup1_loop('1');  -- run with ssg-1 items only
 SELECT transgroup1_loop('2');  -- run with ssg-2 items only

 -- show all with a sequential group label:
 SELECT *, dense_rank() over (ORDER BY id) AS group_label from transgroup1;
```

results:

```
  id |   items   | ssg_label | dels | group_label 
 ----+-----------+-----------+------+-------------
   4 | {8,7,4}   | 1         | {}   |           1
   5 | {9,5,2,1} | 1         | {}   |           2
   6 | {11,10}   | 2         | {}   |           3
```

---

PS: the function `array_uunion()` is the [same as original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20608421/287948),

```
 CREATE FUNCTION array_uunion(anyarray,anyarray) RETURNS anyarray AS $$
     -- ensures distinct items of a concatemation
    SELECT ARRAY(SELECT  unnest($1) UNION SELECT  unnest($2))
 $$ LANGUAGE sql immutable;
```