# Transitive Group Query on 2 Columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need help with a transitive query in SQL Server.

I have a table with [ID] and [GRPID].

I would like to update a third column [NEWGRPID] based on the following logic:

1. For each [ID], get its GRPID;
2. Get all of the IDs associated with the GRPID from (1);
3. Set [NEWGRPID] equal to an integer (variable that is incremented by 1), for all of the rows from step (2)

The idea is several of these IDs are "transitively" linked across different [GRPID]s, and should all be having the same [GRPID].

The below table is the expected result, with [NEWGRPID] populated.

```
ID      GRPID   NEWGRPID
-----   -----   ------
1       345     1
1       777     1
2       777     1
3       345     1
3       777     1
4       345     1
4       999     1
5       345     1
5       877     1
6       999     1
7       877     1
8       555     2
9       555     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN 
        DROP TABLE #tmp;
    END;

SELECT GRPID, count (*) AS GRPCNT
INTO #tmp
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY GRPID

UPDATE TGT
SET TGT.NEWGRPID = SRC.GRPCNT
FROM yourtable TGT
JOIN #tmp ON #tmp.GRPID = TGT.GRPID
```

If the values are likely to change over time you should think about a computed column or a trigger.

Comment: Thanks Pawel. The result returns 3 distinct [NEWGRPID], should return 2 distinct based on logic.
I think what is need is something along the lines of what is in this question, but not sure... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033115/how-to-label-transitive-groups-with-sql

Comment: Is this OK? I'm sorry, I thought you wanted a counter on all rows with matching GRPID. If you need a counter of the pair (ID, GRPID) in the second statement go for SELECT ID, GRPID, COUNT (*) as IDGRPCNT and group by ID, GRPID. Then add ID in join condition in the update statement.

Comment: My mistake, by counter I meant a variable that increments by 1, not a count on rowset. Will try updating question for clarity. 
Thanks.