# Classify records based on matching table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables: ITEMS and MATCHING_ITEMS, as below:

```
ITEMS:
|---------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |       Name       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        A         |
|          2          |        B         |
|          3          |        C         |
|          4          |        D         |
|          5          |        E         |
|          6          |        F         |
|          7          |        G         |
|---------------------|------------------|

MATCHING_ITEMS:
|---------------------|------------------|
|        ID_1         |       ID_2       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        2         |
|          1          |        3         |
|          2          |        3         |
|          4          |        5         |
|          4          |        6         |
|          5          |        6         |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

The MATCHING_ITEMS table defines items that match each other, and thus belong to the same group, i.e. items 1,2, and 3 match with each other and thus belong in a group, and the same for items 4,5, and 6. Item 7 does not have a match belong to any group.

I now need to add a 'Group' column on the ITEMS table which contains a unique integer for each group, so it would look as follows:

```
ITEMS:
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          ID         |       Name       |       Group      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |        A         |        1         |
|          2          |        B         |        1         |
|          3          |        C         |        1         |
|          4          |        D         |        2         |
|          5          |        E         |        2         |
|          6          |        F         |        2         |
|          7          |        G         |       NULL       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

So far I have been using a stored procedure to do this, looping over each line in the MATCHING_ITEMS table and updating the ITEMS table with a group value. The problem is that I eventually need to do this for a table containing millions of records, and the looping method is far too slow.

Is there a way that I can achieve this without using a loop?

Comment: Your matching_items table is a bad idea. As the size of your group increases the number of items in this table will explode. Have you tried it with a group of 10 items? Or do you know that there will be a limit?

Comment: Why not using ID_1 as group id ? it should be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have all pairs of matches in the matching table, then you can just use the minimum id to assign the group.  For this:

```
select i.*,
       (case when grp_id is not null
             then dense_rank() over (order by grp_id)
        end) as grouping
from items i left join
     (select mi.id_1, least(mi.id1, min(mi.id2)) as grp_id
      from matching_items mi
      group by mi.id_1
     ) mi
     on i.id = mi.id_1;
```

Note:  This works only if *all* pairs are in the matching items table.  Otherwise, you will need a recursive/hierarchical query to get all the pairs.

Comment: Thanks, this answer worked well for cases where all matching item-pairs are in the table. I also have cases where not all matching pairs are present, e.g. I have a pair with IDs (1, 2) and a pair with IDs (2, 3), and I would like IDs (1, 2, 3) to be assigned to the same group. Fortunately I now found some suitable answers for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033115/how-to-label-transitive-groups-with-sql), one of which was provided by you six years ago!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `min` and `max` at first, then `dense_rank` to assign group numbers:

```
select id, name, dense_rank() over (order by mn, mx) grp
  from (
    select distinct id, name, 
           min(id_1) over (partition by name) mn, 
           max(id_2) over (partition by name) mx
      from items left join matching_items on id in (id_1, id_2))
  order by id
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c1cb1bfc59f8e0fe2641b01dd6d44913)</sup>**

Answer (score 0):

The pairs 2,3 and 5,6 in the Matching_items table seem redundant as they could be derived (if I am reading your question right)

Here is how I did it. I just reused id_1 from your example as the group no:

```
    create table
    items (
     ID number,
    name varchar2 (2)
    );

    insert into items values (1, 'A');
    insert into items values (2, 'B');
    insert into items values (3, 'C');
    insert into items values (4, 'D');
    insert into items values (5, 'E');
    insert into items values (6, 'F');
    insert into items values (7, 'G');

    create table
    matching_items (
    ID number,
    ID_2 number
    );

    insert into matching_items values (1, 2);
    insert into matching_items values (1, 3);
    insert into matching_items values (2, 3);
    insert into matching_items values (4, 5);
    insert into matching_items values (4, 6);
    insert into matching_items values (5, 6);

    with new_grp as
    (
    select id, id_2, id as group_no
    from matching_items
    where id in (select id from items)
    and id not in (select id_2 from matching_items)),
    assign_grp as
    (
    select id, group_no
    from new_grp
    union
    select id_2, group_no
    from new_grp)
    select items.id, name, group_no
    from items left outer join assign_grp
    on items.id = assign_grp.id;
```